# Is there anyway to turn off the dreaded slot machine date picker in iOS?

Tags: ios, calendar

The date picker in iOS is awful.  Every time I put something on my calendar it's a "game of chance" if I will notified about it.  Combine that with a touch screen and you have a recipe for scheduling disaster.

I would prefer to select a date from a calendar, or heaven-forbid, type it in using the keyboard!!!!!

Is there any way to turn this thing off?

Comment: Oh good I thought I was the only one who thought this particular part of the UX sucked!!!

Comment: There is nothing that says you have to use the built in calendar app. There are many alternatives. I use Calendars 5 which allows natural language appointment entry.

Comment: I totally agree with @Mark. While I don't use the calendar that much and haven't gone looking for other apps, there are plenty of calendar apps available. I'd pull up the store and download a pile of apps and see which works for you. I've heard good things about Sunrise.

Comment: Could you (someone) upload a picture of this dreaded date picker? What does "turn this think off" mean in practice?

Comment: It means replace it with a simple text box.

Comment: Solution: buy an android. There's nothing about android that can't be customized :-)

Comment: @Mark Using another calendar app is not sufficient as the standard date picker control gets used in all other apps e.g. timers

Comment: I set appointments in calendars 5 all the time and never see the date picker.

Comment: Agree, it is terrible. We have a new app for work we use for scheduling on our smart phones. People with iphones have this slot machine style date picker, you have to use a separate calendar to see what day and week to use this date picker. People with android phones, their date pickers come up showing month and it is easy. Apple needs to improve this!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple answer: Nope.

Sorry to disappoint you. I also dislike this new picker. It is found all over the new UI and it is just terrible. Whoever decided this was good design missed the boat.